# convert stack of DICOM Images into vti file

Tags: c#, 3d, dicom

I've downloaded ActiViz.NET 5.8 to use it in my C# application, now the examples I downloaded show 3D by reading a vti file..

How can I create a vti file from a stack of images?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Simply use gdcm2vtk from the command line:

```
$ gdcm2vtk DICOM_input_directory output.vti
```

See [gdcm2vtk man page](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/gdcm2vtk.html). Of course GDCM is wrapped in C# language so the command line can be used from any Activiz.NET + GDCM application.

On debian/linux, simply do:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libvtkgdcm-tools
```

On windows/macosx you'll need to compile GDCM+VTK.

Comment: So no C# Code in my .NET application? I can simply call that script from my app and then read the vti file?

Comment: Both. You can call the compiler binary (C++) or use the C# API, pick whichever you are more familiar with.