# Reading DICOM tags value using ActiViz.NET

Tags: c#, vtk, dicom

I am displaying some DICOM images using `ActiViz.NET` and `C#` with this code:

```
string folder = path;//@"C:\VTKdata";
vtkDICOMImageReader reader = vtkDICOMImageReader.New();
reader.SetDirectoryName(folder);
reader.Update();
```

I need some DICOM tags values, such as `Series Instance UID` and `Patient ID`.
I could only get the `Study Instance UID` from the reader class.
How can I get the value of the DICOM attribute I need ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can, you could use the GDCM C# binding. It is integrated with ActiViz.NET. See other posts such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590457/convert-stack-of-dicom-images-into-vti-file).

For more information see the [vtkGDCMImageReader](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/2.6/html/classvtkGDCMImageReader.html) class, and the GDCM DataSet class. See in particular one of the simpliest example SimplePrint [here](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/2.6/html/SimplePrint_8cs-example.html).

Comment: could you add some more information? SimplePrint  is not a good example for me because I use  vtkDICOMImageReader  for the whole series rather than the reader in the example.

Answer (score 0):

```
vtkMedicalImageReader2* medimg = vtkMedicalImageReader2::New();
medimg->SetFileName(argv[1]);
medimg->Update();
printf("Patient gender: %s\n",medimg->GetMedicalImageProperties()->GetPatientSex());
printf("Age %s\n",medimg->GetMedicalImageProperties()->GetPatientAge());
printf("Modality %s\n",medimg->GetMedicalImageProperties()->GetModality());
```

Comment: It would be better if you would explain your code and why it helps.